# How do I place C++ code coverage data from MSVS2012 to Sonar?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sonarqube

I'm using MSVS 2012, writing in C++.

I use vstest.console.exe utility from MSVS to run tests and then I use CodeCoverage.exe to determine code coverage. As a result I get xml files with code coverage.

My question is - how do I feed these xmls to Sonar?

Comment: Wither it is C++ or C# or some other language in VS, it would be good to have a way of importing the output of CodeCoverage.  I have yet to get the unit tests to run in Gallio and I have them running in my automated build now with vstest.